# View being underutilized in my PHP MVC design

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, model-view-controller

I'm designing my website around MVC. I have a controller.php, view.php and model.php. Lets take my registration logic for example.

I have a UserAuthentication.js class which uses ajax to send registration data to my index.php class. This class uses my controller to send this data to my model, who verifies and writes this data to the database. My model sends a 'registration success' message in return back to the controller, who sends this to my view.php class. My view echos this out as a reply to the initial ajax request made from the UserAuthentication.js class. This reply is used to update the page, say, change the page to say "you have bee registered".

My question is a design one, my view is doing very little. What needs to go there so it has more of a purpose and responsibility? I mean the echo used to reply to ajax could be sent by the index.php or controller class. I only gave it to the view so it had a job.

Comment: If you're just returning json for a SPA etc, then you will have a lighter view codebase compared to rendering out deeply nested templates and components with many partials etc. Its about separation of concerns, in a traditional MVC app, if you had no *view* in MVC then you would have enormous controllers ;p

Comment: Don't do MVC for the sake of doing MVC, do MVC because it makes sense to do it.  If it ajax, or any RESTish type stuff, then I don't use a view.  Consider returning XML would you build the XML in the view just for the sake of having a view.  Or would you use SimpleXML, with is output buffering and ability to flush partial content.  It's like a download, do you need a View to download a CSV, maybe the page with the button, but not the actual download.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix college assignment, if it weren't worth marks i would not be using it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case your view only needs to be the response (probably in a JSON format). I agree that this is not much and I will admit that sometimes I just skip the view and print the JSON string straight from the controller.

In general all you need to do there:

1. Set the proper headers (XML, JSON, text, etc..)
2. Print the result

That's it :)

Comment: Say it ain't so ... you put all the views out of work, what will they tell the mrs. view and the baby views....